# How to handle single websocket connection for all chats in Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I want to make a chat application like WhatsApp, and I want to make the backend server using Django Channels to handle all the real-time updates.

I have been exploring various sources but I could not figure out one thing about how do i manage single websocket connection (single endpoint) for each user and still receive messages from all the chats he is part of in real time. As per my current understanding, I can add channel(web socket connection corresponding to a user) to different channel groups but what if a user is part of a lot of groups(basically is eligible to receive updates from various chats)? Should I add that channel to all the groups, he can be part of as soon as the connection is established or is there any workaround like one in my mind:

1. Store the list of channels corresponding to each user in a database.
2. Make a `for` loop so that whenever a message is received by server, it sends message to websocket connections corresponding to each user involved to receive that message?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for a simple chat system, you should just add the user's channel name to the groups he's subscribed to.

However, you definitely will need to model the chat system in the database for a more complex system. Let's say you have a model Chat, ChatMember and Message. When a user connects to the websocket, he does not need to specify any chat because it is a general connection. Any message sent by the client has to specify the chat, so you can loop through the chat members and forward the message to all who are currently connected.

How do you know who is currently connected? this is the tricky part. In my architecture, I have a group for each user, sort of like an inbox. The group name is generated from the user id. Each user can have several connections, say mobile, web etc. All the connections coming from a user is added to the users group and the user's number of active connection is saved in an Inbox model. With new connections, it is incremented and decremented during disconnections.

So to know which chat members are currently online, I can just check that the user's inbox has atleast one connection. If he is online I forward the message to his ibox group, else i store the message in his inbox. Whenever a user connects, he is sent all the messages in his inbox and the inbox is cleared.

This is just an example of a way to implement it but you can also think up a custom architecture or improve on it.